# Why are notifications not grouped by tag on iOS 16.4 using Safari?

Tags: ios, push-notification, safari, service-worker, web-push

we implemented push notifications for a PWA using this guide: https://web.dev/notifications/

We are using the `tag` property to group notifications together. For example, if there is one reply, the user will be shown "you have a new reply". But if there is another, it should show "you have 2 new replies" and replace the previous one.

This is the relevant code in our service worker:

```js
self.addEventListener('push', async function (event) {
  const payload = event.data?.json()
  if (!payload) return
  const { tag } = payload.options
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    if (!['REPLY', 'MENTION'].includes(tag)) {
      // notifications with REPLY and MENTION as tags need updated title.
      // other notifications can just replace the old one
      return self.registration.showNotification(payload.title, payload.options)
    }

    const notifications = await self.registration.getNotifications({ tag })
    // since we used a tag filter, there should only be zero or one notification
    if (notifications.length > 1) {
      console.error(`more than one notification with tag ${tag} found`)
      return null
    }
    if (notifications.length === 0) {
      return self.registration.showNotification(payload.title, payload.options)
    }
    const currentNotification = notifications[0]
    const amount = currentNotification.data?.amount ? currentNotification.data.amount + 1 : 2
    let title = ''
    if (tag === 'REPLY') {
      title = `You have ${amount} new replies`
    } else if (tag === 'MENTION') {
      title = `You were mentioned ${amount} times`
    }
    currentNotification.close()
    const { icon } = currentNotification
    return self.registration.showNotification(title, { icon, tag, data: { url: '/notifications', amount } })
  })())
})
```

A notification that we send to the push service may look like this:

```json
{
  "title": "you have a new reply",
  "options": {
    "body": <text of reply>,
    "timestamp": <unix timestamp>,
    "icon": "/android-chrome-96x96.png",
    "tag": "REPLY",
    "data": { "url": "/items/124101" },
  }
}
```

This works on Android but for some reason does not on iOS 16.4 with Safari. Notifications never get replaced. So if a user gets 3 replies, they get three "you have a new reply" notification. I checked the browser compatibility for various related features but I couldn't find a reason why it shouldn't work.

Example:

- `Notification` support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification#browser_compatibility
- `tag` support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/tag#browser_compatibility
- `showNotification` support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification#browser_compatibility
- "using the Notification API" support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#browser_compatibility

I also looked through the specification for the Notification API and it clearly says that notifications with the same tag should get replaced:

> 6.3 Run the show steps for *notification*

-- https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-serviceworkerregistration-shownotification

> Let oldNotification be the notification in the list of notifications whose tag is not the empty string and is notification’s tag, and whose origin is same origin with notification’s origin, if any, and null otherwise.
>
> If oldNotification is non-null, then:
>
> Handle close events with oldNotification.
>
> If the notification platform supports replacement, then:
>
> Replace oldNotification with notification, in the list of notifications.

-- https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#show-steps

Since support for these features was only added recently (in 16.4 which shipped on 2023-03-27), I didn't find useful resources on the web about this. Mostly about people asking when support will come.

Since I have no access to a Apple device, I can not debug this properly.

As mentioned, I looked through the specification and browser compatibility and couldn't find a reason why this code does not work on iOS but works on Android.

We would be very happy if someone can help us with this.

Comment: A notification with the same tag must replace the previous notifications that have the same tag, you are correct. You need to report this bug to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) or to WebKit (https://bugs.webkit.org).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I filed a bug report with WebKit now: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=258922